# UICollectionView - add bottom inset for entire collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiedgeinsets

I have a `UICollectionView` with multiple sections.

I would like to add bottom inset to the entire collectionView.

All the Q&As suggest to use the following function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
       insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
```

But this adds insets to all the sections. Where I need space only it the bottom of the collectionView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom:<#someValue#>, right: 0)
```